# Click on menu item redirects to undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, padding

```
<li class="dropdown navbar-li col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <a href="<%= ESRBOrg.Core.Common.PublisherConfigurationManager.Navigation %>index.aspx" class="dropdown-toggle navPadding">PUBLISHERS</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu col-md-12 col-sm-12  navbar-submenus"role="menu">
        <li><a href="<%= ESRBOrg.Core.Common.PublisherConfigurationManager.Navigation %>Getting_Rated/Index.aspx">Getting a Game Rated</a></li>
        <li><a href="<%= ESRBOrg.Core.Common.PublisherConfigurationManager.Navigation %>ratings/index.aspx">Rating Certificate Updates</a></li>
        <li><a href="<%= ESRBOrg.Core.Common.PublisherConfigurationManager.Navigation %>ArcManual.aspx">Advertising &amp; Marketing <BR />Guidelines</a></li>
        <li><a href="<%= ESRBOrg.Core.Common.PublisherConfigurationManager.Navigation %>Library.aspx">Downloads</a></li>
        <li><a href="<%= ESRBOrg.Core.Common.PublisherConfigurationManager.Navigation %>ratings/enforcement.aspx">Enforcement</a></li>
        <li><a href="<%= ESRBOrg.Core.Common.PublisherConfigurationManager.Navigation %>about/contact.aspx">Contact ESRB</a></li>
        <li><a href="<%= ESRBOrg.Core.Common.PublisherConfigurationManager.Navigation %>PreClearance.aspx">ARC Pre-Clearance</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

When I hover on `<a>` tag and click - everything works good. 
But `<a>` doesn't cover all `<li>` element (I add padding). And when I click on padding area I am redirected to undefined.

How can i fix this without changing my existing style of page (don't remove padding)?

Some hardly reproduced example http://jsfiddle.net/v3ng6zqh/

Js script that i hardly find in code :

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('li.dropdown').hover(function () {
        $(this).addClass("open");
    });

    $('li.dropdown').mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).removeClass("open");
    });

    $('li.dropdown').off("click");
    $('li.dropdown').on("click", function(e) {
        var navigate = $(this).hasClass("open");
        if (navigate) {
            window.location = $(this).find("a[data-toggle='dropdown']").prop("href");
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: um, clicking on an li should not do anything. Is there JavaScript involved that you are not showing?

Comment: What URL are you sending them to?

Comment: @epascarello, so i need to add some script to enable clicking on li tags?

Comment: In that code above, clicking on the LI should not redirect the window. I am saying: is there something in the code that is doing it? Sounds like something is listening to the event.target and pulling off the href.

Comment: @epascarello, " is there something in the code that is doing it?" - well, i have `href` for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to bind the action to the `li` containing the `a` directly instead of the parent `li`. Also, it would be unnecessary to check if has class `open` since it always will have it (you're adding it on mouse-hover and binding mouse-click). Try this code:

```
$('ul.dropdown-menu li').on("click", function(e) {
  window.location = $(this).find("a").prop("href");
});
```

Comment: according to existing code, i think it's the simplest solution

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a padding inside the `li`, you could add a padding to the `a` element. With a little bit of tweaking it would look the same, but the `a` would cover the entire `li`.

Comment: that would work! BUT if you are exact and the "don't remove padding" in the OP's question is mandatory then the answer should actually be no ;-)

Comment: yes, your right of course. I just thought the input could be of value nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

`<a>` is an inline element. So it'll not cover the whole li. To do that, use this CSS:

```
.dropdown-menu li {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-menu li > a {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

<s>And make sure you don't apply any padding on dropdown-menu li, apply on dropdown-menu li a.</s>

About that undefined redirect, there is a javascript working behind it. Post it here so that I can see.

Comment: display:block; won't stretch the <a> outside of the padding leaving to the conclusion that this answer is wrong...

Comment: @ITroubs I've written **And make sure you don't apply any padding on dropdown-menu li, apply on dropdown-menu li a** if you read it, though.

Comment: I think the OP clearly stated the following `don't remove padding`

Comment: @ITroubs Didn't notice that. Updated the answer.